# Angular 5 - Change body and html5 style

Tags: angular

This used to work before...now it's not working anymore. Maybe some concept change on Angular 5 ? I just need to set the style properties of the body and html elements. Any clue ?

app.component.scss

```
 body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: verdana !important;
  background-color: blue;
 }
```

and this:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Comment: Put the html/body styles in global `styles.scss` - the styles inside the `*.component.scss` are encapsulated for that component only by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default all angular styles are scoped to their component so adding styles to html/body tags from inside the app component (or any component) won't work.

Add those to the *styles.scss* file. Or if you insist you can  try adding this to your `@component({ ..., encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None })`

Comment: I didnt say it was you. And I do accept downvotes, but I just like when specify a reason for downvoting!

Comment: I did beacuse that should have been a comment instead of an answer. If you intend to post it as an answer, please explain your answer in some detail - it'll also benefit whoever stumbles upon this problem in future.

Comment: @Faisal, thanks for the comment. In my opinion, my answer is enough for OP to know what the issue in his code is, and provides a solution/alternative to his problem. How are answers supposed to be written otherwise?

Comment: This was your original answer, `By default all angular styles are scoped to their component so adding styles to html/body tags from inside the app component (or any component) won't work.` - and I downvoted based on that. Instead of an alternate solution, i'll put the styles in global styles.scss. we don't really have to use `ViewEncapsulation.None` here in my opinion.

Comment: You are right! I agree with you, that answer was not enough in itself. Sorry for the confusion. But please consider commenting whenever you downvote! After all, we are all just trying to help each other as a community.